# UNION SELECT different table structure Access or MSSQL

Tags: ms-access, union

Is there any solution combine 2 table with different structure

I try to use UNION select but since the 2 tables are different structure cannot handle it.

Table 1
  ID  |NAME|
  1    John
  2    Ed
  3    Anderson

Table 2
  ID|NAME    |Address
  1  John     USA
  2  Ed       UK
  3  Anderson JPN

Result I need
  ID|NAME  |Address
  1  John
  1  John     USA
  2  Ed
  2  Ed       UK
  3  Anderson
  3  Anderson JPN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can union them if you do something like this,

```
SELECT ID, NAME, 'DUMMY' as ADDRESS
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT ID, NAME, ADDRESS
FROM Table2
```

Comment: Where `'Dummy'` in your case would be `''` or `null`.

Comment: cool, it work for some reason when                                  I used SELECT ID, NAME, 'DUMMY' as ADDRESS
FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT ID, NAME, ADDRESS
FROM Table2                         The table2 appear first is there anyway I can force to show Table1

Comment: What do you mean, "force to show Table1"?  I don't understand.

Comment: The result becomes like this 

ID|NAME |Address
1 John USA
1 John
2 Ed UK
2 Ed
3 Anderson JPN 
3 Anderson

I need result like this
ID|NAME |Address
1 John
1 John USA
2 Ed
2 Ed UK
3 Anderson
3 Anderson JPN

Comment: Is it an order problem then?  Just reverse the tables, `SELECT ... FROM Table2 UNION SELECT ... FROM Table1`

Comment: You might try something like this: `SELECT ID, NAME, Null As ADDRESS, 1 As SOURCE FROM Table1 UNION SELECT ID, NAME, ADDRESS, 2 As SOURCE FROM Table2 ORDER BY ID, SOURCE`.  If you need to, create another query (or an outer SELECT clause) to select only ID, NAME, and ADDRESS (and exclude SOURCE).

Comment: To clarify something implied in Brian's comment: a `UNION` query only supports a single `ORDER BY` clause, at the end, that sorts the whole result set.